# How can I throttle requests per minute in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, request, throttling

I want to be able to say that if a request from the same user (for an API) starts to happen quickly enough that their requests per minute reaches a certain level, I want to start denying the requests until it slows down. ([Just like the guys at Zendesk did](http://www.zendesk.com/api/rest-introduction)).

The question is two fold, what's an efficient way of calculating the request rate (minimal DB read/writes) and where in the MVC hierarchy (Action filter, Controller method override?) would this code best reside?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @MatthewAbbott Thanks much, not sure how I missed that one the search I made only found PHP results, voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Two words, Reactive Framework.

It has all sorts of candy and sugary syntax to get throttling and managing of events to become less and less of a head ache, while I would bet will trickle back through and kill some complexity down stream.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609 Download that and google a tutorial on using it, its similar to using linq on lists but its pushing events at you instead of you pulling elements out.