# ASP.NET MVC - Timer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timer

I am trying to implement something in ASP.NET MVC where I can make each user perform an action once every *n* minutes.

I have come across controls such as Timer but, not quite sure what to use. I would like it so that when the user performs the action, a timer begins to count down from, for example, 3 minutes to 0:00. Once the 3 minutes have lapsed, the user will be able to perform the action again.

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Would I need a Timer Control?

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect solution here: [Best way to implement request throttling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc) created by SO team.

Basically the idea is to store page hits for each user in the cache and then respond to a request based on your logic.

Comment: Sounds like a sledge hammer for cracking a nut for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to save the time of the last action in the session and on subsequent requests check whether it has been more than 3 minutes. For example:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(){
     if (Session["LastAction"] == null || (DateTime.Now - (DateTime)(Session["LastAction"])).Minutes > 3){
          // do action
          Session["LastAction"] = DateTime.Now;
          return View("OK. action executed");
     }
     else{
          return View("Please wait");
     }
}
```

Comment: This seems feasible and makes clear sense. I shall try this out!

Comment: What if the user deletes cookies? Will this method still work?

Comment: No, it won't. If you want it to be related to the user you will always have a possibility of circumventing it. If he opens another browser it won't work either.

Comment: @Subby no it won't. Unless you store your session in the URL.

Comment: Would it therefore be wise to store the time against the User in the database?

Comment: If the user is authenticated, sure.

Comment: It would be a possibility. If you have a logged in user, you could also store it in the application-object. That way it's not depending on cookies

Comment: Would using this "Application-object" be better than storing the value in the database against the User?

Comment: It would certainly be easier. You just replace `Session` with `HttpContext.Application` (and of course add an identifier for the user, since application is shared by everyone, whereas session is a per user object). In terms of what's the best solution, it all depends on your architecture and requirements

Comment: Right okie doke. I'll research in to HttpContext.Application.

Comment: When I do: HttpContext.Current.Application[user.Username] = DateTime.Now().ToString(); - it says it doesn't recognise Current.

Comment: It should be `HttpContext.Application`. You should get rid of `Current`

Comment: I get a null reference when doing:   DateTime lastEarn = (DateTime)HttpContext.Application[user.Username];

Comment: Well, the first time there's probably no value yet, so the cast will fail. You should do a null check before doing this. I have updated my answer

Comment: I saw my mistake immediately after posting the comment and did exactly as how you have deduced. The problem which I can see however is that the Null check succeeds on the 3rd or 4th request.... Why is this?

Comment: Well, surely there must be something in there then. Have you checked the value?

Comment: When running for the first time, the value is null and it gets assigned. When I try again, every works fine. When I try once more, the value turns out to be null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery-timer http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

Basic use would be disable button, invoke timer and then re-enable button when it completes.

However, if you want to post back in the interim this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to achieve this is implementing a job scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) and defining proper job (what has to be done) and proper trigger (when/how often has to be done). With Quartz you can also implement much more complex conditions ("do it every Monday" etc).

Hope it will help.