# How do I return a message from a custom attribute back to my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, custom-attributes, asp.net-mvc-5

I've implemented a throttling mechanism on my Login-action following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1) post. It works the way I want it to, except one thing. Whenever the mechanism is returning my message, I get redirected to a new, blank view with my message in it.

Is it possible, and if so how, to return this message back to my login-controller / view so it can be displayed in my _LoginPage.cshtml?

Here's my attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int AllowedRetries { get; set; }
    private int _loginAttempts = 1;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string key = string.Concat(Name, "-", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress);
        bool allowExecute = false;
        _loginAttempts++;

        while (_loginAttempts <= AllowedRetries)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[key] == null)
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(key,
                true, 
                null, 
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Seconds),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.Low,
                null); 

            allowExecute = true;
        }

        if (!allowExecute)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
            {
                Message = "AllowedRetries Exceeded. You have to wait {n} seconds.";
            }

            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
            {
                // TODO: Redirect message text to login-view
                Content = Message.Replace("{n}" , Seconds.ToString())
            }; 

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
[Throttle(Name = "LoginThrottle", Seconds = 10, AllowedRetries = 3)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model)
{
    ...login logic...

    return View(model);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Following @lin's suggestion I got the information I wanted, but I'm not able to display it in my view. In my cshtml file I start by setting a variable before referencing it further down in my markup:

```
@{
    var informationToUser = ViewBag.Information ?? "";
}
<div class="panel panel-primary>
    ...
    <p>@informationToUser</p>
</div>
```

Still, nothing happens :( As mentioned in comments below, my url now looks like this: `http://localhost:54508/?information=AllowedRetries%20Exceeded.%20You%20have%20to%20wait%2010%20seconds.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want. But it should work. See below code:

**Throttle Attribute**

```
  if (!allowExecute)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
        {     
            Message = "AllowedRetries Exceeded. You have to wait {n} seconds.";
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;

        var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
                action = "Login",
                controller = "Account",
                exceptiontext = Message.Replace("{n}", Seconds.ToString())
        });
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
    }
```

**Login Action Method**

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl, string exceptiontext)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.Exceptiontext = exceptiontext;
        return View();
    }
```

**Update:** You don't need to validate if the ViewBag is null.

**Login View**

```
 //
<div class="panel panel-primary>
    <p>@ViewBag.Exceptiontext </p>
</div>
//
```

The URL should like :

```
http://localhost:58929/Account/Login?exceptiontext=AllowedRetries%20Exceeded.%20You%20have%20to%20wait%2010%20seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've set a breakpoint in both LoginController.cs and ThrottleAttribute.cs. So, it triggers after x amount of failed login attempts and it fills out the values object properly. However, it does not seem to return back to my Index action in LoginController.cs when doing `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);`

Suggestions?

Comment: Disregard that. I noticed that my url is containing the following: `http://localhost:54508/?information=AllowedRetries%20Exceeded.%20You%20have%20to%20wait%2010%20seconds.#`. Now, I guess it's just a matter of updating my view somehow. Doing `@ViewBag.information` in my view displays nothing :(

Comment: hi @NicklasWinger, I guess you should check how did you display the information using the ViewBag.information, because it works for me.

Comment: I got why you have the problem. Your URL is wrong. See my update.

Comment: Url was right. Turned out some other developer had implemented a similar Index action further down in the controller. Got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

I developed an OSS project called [MvcFlash](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=MvcFlash) that does exactly what you want to do and handles a lot of what you want. You can install it through NuGet and it is easy to get started with.

```
PM > Install-Package MvcFlash.Web
```

Using it in code is as simple as this.

```
// In your attribute
Flash.Error("Ooops", "There was an exception", id: "Exception")
```

In your view:

```
@Html.Flash()
```

The reason you need the **id** in the attribute is because the attribute might execute multiple times and thus you would see the message multiple times when you call flash. Setting the **id** makes the message unique.

Here is some more information.

https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/MvcFlash2