# Can you detect a redirect from ActionExecutingContext in an ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We implemented a user throttle similar to the one described in this SO question: [Best way to implement request throttling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc)

However, we have run into a problem. We have certain actions that result in a redirect. Our throttle is treating the redirect the same as any other user generated request and triggers the "you must wait" portion of the code even though the user had nothing to do with the second action.

We have tried modifying the throttle to only trigger if the action and controller are the same but we have situations where we make changes to the url and redirect internally to normalize the url or add query string parameters, etc.

We basically want to tell the throttle to ignore all internally generated redirects because we meant for those to happen but I can't find a way to detect that the request is the result of a redirect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the only way you're going to be able to manage that is by setting some sort of flag (session, cookie, on the URL) so that when the redirected GET occurs you can check if that flag has been set. Because the redirect is actually brokered by the browser it looks like any other GET request.

Comment: @CraigW. Based on the fact that this question didn't get any answers, and that I couldn't find another way, I believe you are correct but we did come up with a better solution...I think. Adding it as an answer to this question below.

Answer (score 0):

After searching everywhere, we decided that this approach would not work and was not available.

In the end we decided to write our own redirects to remove the throttle cache key prior to performing the redirect. These new redirects give us more control and better flexibility and prevent our users from crashing into our throttle just because the app redirected them (which wasn't their fault).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string action = "MyAction";
        string controller = "MyController";

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action, controller}));
    }
```