# Dynamic Ip Restriction on Runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dynamic-ip

I want to add/remove IP restriction on run time to a MVC 5 project.

I did a search and found two ways.

1. Change Dynamic Ip Restriction module on runtime.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Text;
   using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

   internal static class Sample
       {
          private static void Main()
          {
             using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
             {
                Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                ConfigurationSection ipSecuritySection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity", "Default Web Site");
                ConfigurationElementCollection ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();



      ConfigurationElement addElement = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("add");
        addElement["ipAddress"] = @"192.168.100.1";
        addElement["allowed"] = false;
        ipSecurityCollection.Add(addElement);

        ConfigurationElement addElement1 = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("add");
        addElement1["ipAddress"] = @"169.254.0.0";
        addElement1["subnetMask"] = @"255.255.0.0";
        addElement1["allowed"] = false;
        ipSecurityCollection.Add(addElement1);

        serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
          }
        }
   ```

In this way, does `serverManager.CommitChanges` restart the IIS or application ?

2. [Best way to implement request throttling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I will use throttling for this purpose.

If the application or IIS hasn't been restarted, I would prefer first way because it's on IIS level.

Do you have any suggestion which one is the best or any other approaches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way restarts the application. Second way is working on action level (objects are created already).

Therefore, I'm blocking/redirecting request on Begin_Request. I'm adding ips which I want to block to cache. Then I'm reading cache value on begin request if request ip is in blacklist I'm redirecting it to 404.html.

```
  private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var mylifeTimeScope = IoCBootstrap.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {

            var ipHelper = mylifeTimeScope.Resolve<IIpHelper>();
            if (ipHelper.BlackListIp())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("404.html");
            }
         }
    }
```

`ipHelper.BlackListIp()` checks ip is in blacklist or not.